# Comparing swaps with bonds

Tags: fixed-income, bond, swaps

Swaps and bonds have a lot of similarity although one is a security and the other is a derivative.
For example,

1. libor for swaps is like repo rate bonds (thinking them both as the funding leg)
2. fixed payment is like bond's coupon

I feel that there could be a systematic way to link or think about them under the same framework/logic. All the concepts in bonds must have a similar concepts in swaps and vice verse?

For example,

1. what is for bonds as annuity for swaps ?
2. what is for swaps as yield for bonds ?